# expose JSON in JOB pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Now I am using json output to expose my transformation as rest web service, that's OK, but I m looking for the same thing but this time for a job, is there is a way to expose a job kettle as rest web service.

Comment: Have you looked at Carte?

Comment: when i run a job by carte, i got this                                                   <webresult>
  <result>OK</result>
  <message>Job started</message>
  <id>ee6b7710-7435-48ac-81c6-3380133c1209</id>
</webresult>          I want to expose results or errors instead of this message??